# Android, получить код из СМС

Tags: android, sms

Вопрос настиг следующего характера. Есть Android приложение, активация в котором происходит средствами ввода пароля из СМС что приходят на указанный пользователем номер. Хочу реализовать автоматическую подстановку кода при получении СМС из конкретного номера.

На данный момент наткнулся на полное непонимание данной процедуры, посоветуйте что бы почитать, так как готовые решения из простор сети не работают, возможно из-за морального устаревания.

Спасибо.

Comment: Перестаньте этого хотеть. Внимательные пользователи очень не любят запрос разрешений на чтение sms. Вдруг вы решите с какого-то момента читать коды в смс от банка или от оператора с паролем от лк, например...

Comment: Yura Ivanov, хорошее замечание, но все же для своего развития бы понять что да как не помешает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну почему же не работают - есть много решений. Как вариант, через getContentResolver().

Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739800/how-to-read-sms-code-from-your-android-app) более детально. И не забудь добавить разрешение в манифест.

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть)